# How to find the module 'posix' in python?

Tags: python, macos, posix

I've seen this [Python: "import posix" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382266/python-import-posix-question) on how to find out a lot of information on the posix module. I still want to take a peek at the C code. Is there any way to do that, or is that code magicly hidden away and only the compiled version is included?

I wouldn't mind seeing the compiled version too to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

The C file is called [`Modules/posixmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c) in the Python source distribution.

The 'compiled version' is not a separate file but part of the Python shared library (it is one of the built-in modules, like `sys` and several others).